# while file writing mode how to backspace work at C

Tags: c

*Sorry guys, i am not good at english. So hard to explain. also i edited misstake.*

i did write data and write '\n' and then when data writing is End, want backspace to make EOF after data.

```
FILE *fout;
fopen_s(&fout, FILENAME, "wt");
char data[3] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    fputc(data[i], fout);
    fputc('\n', fout);
}
fputc('\b', fout); // to make EOF after String
fclose(fout);
```

file write ex)

```
A (i don't want)  A (i want)
B                 B
C                 C(EOF)
(EOF)
```

but i tried '\b' it doesn't work, just show circle symbol thing.

Comment: Welcome! It is not very clear what you are asking. Can you please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem. You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please make an [mre]. That will simplify describing where in your code you should not write a newline and where to do it instead.

Comment: It looks like an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: [`'\b'`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) is a character that does not have any special meaning in a file. A terminal _could_ interpret it as a [backspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace), meaning it will move the cursor one column to the left, allowing the next character to be typed over the one before the `'\b'` (overwriting it visually). If such a "next character" is not printed, the cursor remains under/over the character that precedes the `'\b'`. The backspace character does not remove it.

Comment: You're misusing `fopen_s()`.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019  Of course, using `fopen_s()` won't improve the security of your application, but it will result in non-portable code

Comment: I don't see any `\n` in your code.

Comment: Sorry guys, i am not good at english. So hard to explain. also i edited misstake.

Comment: `\b` will not backspace the file pointer,   Instead, use: `fseek()` to move the file pointer back one character, then use `truncate()` to trim off the last character

Comment: You can try any on-line translator to get better English. But please check the translation that it matches your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a back space in a file won't erase the last character written to the file, it just will write the `\b` value (which is 8 I think) to the file.

Also your code writes a NUL character after each character written, which is strange (if not wrong) for a text file. I suppose you want to write a text file because you open the file with `"wt"`.

You probably want this:

```
FILE *fout;
fout = fopen(FILENAME, "wt");  // you probbaly want fopen here, not fopen_s
if (fout == NULL)              // fopen can fail
{
  // show error message and abort
  ...
}
char data[3] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    fputc(data[i], fout);   // write character
    if (i <= 2)
      fputc('\n', fout);    // write a line ending if we're not on the last line
}

fclose(fout);
```

The file will contain 3 lines, and the last line won't end with a `\n`.

It will look like this:

```
A
B
C
```

Comment: thank you so much. that's what i want.